# For all strings s1 in table change all substrings s2 to substrings s3

Tags: postgresql

There is a table `t1(id int, string1 varchar(15), string2 varchar(15), string3 varchar(15))`. How can I write a request that returns a table `(id int, res1 varchar(200))` in which res1 is s1 in which all entries of substring s2 changed to substring s3?

For example if t1 contains 2 strings:
`(0, 'catcat', 'cat',  'dog')
(1, 'dddod', 'd', 'a')` result should be a table
`(0, 'dogdog')
(1, 'aaaoa')`

Comment: What do you mean by `substring s2` and `substring s3` ? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55992301/edit) your question and add  some sample data and also expected result in **plain text** only

Comment: Why did it become  `dogdog ` from  `catcat ` if you want substring s2 changed to substring s3 ? It actually changed from s3 to s2 and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

May be using a simple `replace`?

```
select id, replace(string1,string2,string3) from t1;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d82f74c586252cf4c3fb248b1c16ca06)